# エラーにする vs. エラーをする

Tags: grammar

```
In XXX case, the app gives an error.

何々をしたら、また何々の場合は、アプリにエラーメッセージを表示する。
```

これをもっと簡潔に、単純にエラーが起きることを表現したいです。下記のどっちのほうが正しいでしょうか？

1. エラーにする。
2. エラーをする。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

エラーをする ("to do an error"?) is ungrammatical regardless of the context. エラーにする can mean "to make/call/consider it an error", but it does not make sense in this context.

Instead, this "gives an error" can be translated like this:

- ～の場合はエラー**になる** (or エラーになります)
- ～の場合はエラー**が発生する** (or エラーが発生します)
- ～の場合はエラー**が起きる** (or エラーが起きます)

Comment: Is it not possible then to 'make an error' in the transitive sense? e.g. "Bob made an error in his calculation". Must we say "An error occurred in Bob's calculation" instead? I'm assuming I could use something like 間違いをする, but I can't use エラー in this case?

Comment: @user3856370 間違い as in 間違いをする means "wrongdoing". In this regard, エラー as in エラーをする can only mean "error" as in baseball, not errors in general.

Comment: @user3856370 In addition to being pretty common in baseball parlance, "エラーをする" can be used, albeit with limitations, in the sense of "make an error" in certain other (technical) registers. (Examples in [here](https://www.jreast.co.jp/development/tech/pdf_3/02-03.pdf) and [here](https://www.jsse.or.jp/cabinets/cabinet_files/download/282/06a91ef5281e23616eff5db5dbbb1e0b?frame_id=1996), both written by highly educated Japanese, and I find them perfectly grammatical.)
Another (and probably more common) transitive verb that can be used with "エラー" is "犯す".

Comment: @user4092 "Wrongdoing" often describes behavior that is *morally/ethically* wrong, but I don't think that was the intended meaning when you said "間違い as in 間違いをする means "wrongdoing"", since "間違い" can refer to any kind of mistakes, including moral/ethical ones?